# How to prevent page from scrolling when asp validators fails witha a pop up window

Tags: validation, validationsummary

My page has ASP validations. When validation fails and error pop up is displayed, the page is scrolled down and the `div` container moves down.

How can I prevent this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution here: [Solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/1545969.aspx?How%20To%20prevent%20a%20page%20with%20ValidationSummary%20to%20jump%20to%20top%20position%20after%20failed%20validation%20)

This javascript code will do the trick:

```
 window.scrollTo = function (x, y) {
     return true;
 }
```